# Sketch a graph from given limits

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

How would look like a graph: 
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f(x) = 1}\\
\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} f(x) = 1}\\
\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 1}\\
\end{array}\right.$$

I tried it loads of time, but I dont have a clue how to realize it

Comment: The constant function $f(x)=1$ satisfies these conditions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained the constant function $f:x\mapsto 1$ verifies your condition. If you want something less trivial you could go for (one example among infinitely many!)

$$f : x\mapsto \arctan(x-1) \cdot e^{-(x-1)^2}$$

[image]